# How to return specific dates based on multiple conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table below (its test dates, not all dates are included) and I need to return specific dates based on quarterly and fiscal year periods.

```
reportdate  periodtype
2021-11-12  wk
2021-11-19  wk
2021-11-30  mth
2021-12-03  wk
2021-12-10  wk
2021-12-31  mth
2022-01-07  wk
2022-01-14  wk
2022-01-28  wk
2022-01-31  mth
2022-02-04  wk
```

I have a condition which I am having difficulty writing in SQL.

For the fiscal year I need to return the all the month end report dates plus the latest weekly reportdate. This I am able to to do using this code:

```
reportDate between @YTD_Start_Dt and @report_dt and (periodtype = 'mth' or reportDate =@report_dt)
```

There is a case which occurs the first week of every month (in this case 2022-02-04) where the last monthly report is sometimes not available until the second week. Therefore I need to return all available monthly dates plus the latest weekly plus the last weeks report in the month prior.

So for 2022-02-04 I would need to return:

```
--if current day is less than 8 then return:
2021-11-30
2021-12-31 
2022-01-28 
2022-02-04 

--if current day is greater or equal to 8 then return    
2021-11-30
2021-12-31
2022-01-31
2022-02-04
```

I don't know how to write the logic so that it returns the correct combo of reportdates depending on what is available. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You say *if the last monthly report is not available* - should this actually say "if the current day is less than 8" ?

Comment: Yes, I will update the post

Comment: Isn't it the same as the last (mth/wk) report available for every month?

Comment: i think you should change the input dataset as well based on two scenarios. will you have same dataset in both the cases ?

Answer (score 1):

How about..

```
where
    (reportDate between @YTD_Start_Dt and DATEADD(day, -8, @report_dt) and periodtype  = 'mth') or
    (reportDate between DATEADD(day, -6, @report_dt) and @report_dt and periodtype  = 'wk') or
    (DAY(@report_dt) < 8 AND periodtype  = 'wk' and reportDate between DATEADD(d, -6, EOMONTH(@report_dt, -1)) AND EOMONTH(@n, -1))
```

.. where it's a

- `mth` type and the record is between year start and 8 days prior (removes the latest mth if it's the first week of the month after) or
- `wk` type in the last week or
- it's the first week of the month and is a `wk` report from the ultimate 7 days of last month